# JavaFX MediaPlayer not always playing MP4 file

Tags: java, maven, javafx, fxml, javafx-11

I have a very simple JavaFX video player which in some runs just doesn't play the MP4 file it should be playing.
Here's the source code (I omitted the imports for convenience):

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        videoPlayer(stage);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    private void videoPlayer(Stage stage) {
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();

        File mediaFile = new File("src/main/resources/Lost   End Credits.mp4");

        MediaView moviePlayer;
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(new Media(mediaFile.toURI().toString()));

        moviePlayer = new MediaView(player);

        moviePlayer.setPreserveRatio(true);
        moviePlayer.fitWidthProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty());
        moviePlayer.fitHeightProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty());

        player.setAutoPlay(true);
        player.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);

        pane.getChildren().add(moviePlayer);
        player.play();

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

And these are my dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
        <version>14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I also have some plugins:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <release>11</release>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.6</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>default-cli</id>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.example.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

And these are multiple runs of the program, notice how some of them (runs 2,8,10) don't display the video (the black screen means it's playing, gray means the video doesn't appear):

https://youtu.be/q4ujOCILeOs

What could be causing this kind of problem?

Tried debugging as much as I can with my current knowledge of JavaFX, I expect to get a clarification about a detail (most likely related to concurrency) that I missed and causes the issue

Comment: Don’t mix versions. You have 14 for the media module and 11 for other JavaFX modules.  Use current software, 19, for the JDK and *all* JavaFX dependencies, and 0.0.8 for the plugin. You don’t need commons io for this, so get rid of it.

Comment: Also, since you have set autoplay to true, do you really need ```player.play()```? With consistent dependencies (in my case running your code, javafx version = 17.0.2), your code runs just fine no matter how many times I launch/quit, and no matter how fast I cycle between quitting and launching (as fast as I can hit Command-Q and press the run button in Eclipse).

Comment: @jewelsea I'm afraid this didn't solve it, I updated the JDK and all my dependencies to version 19, including updating the plugin. In some runs the video just doesn't play. I use commons io for a separate functionality of the program.
I also tried running a single video and then switching to another mid run using a key event. and in some runs one video will play but the other will not.